# Colour Table Cell Based on Value with PHP

Tags: php, html

I generate a html table from a mysql query and am wanting to colour cells based on the value of `.$result->Games.`. For argument sake, if the value of games is less than 10 I'd like the cell to be red and if it is greater than 40 I'd like the cell to be green. I'd also like to be able to colour anything between 10 and 40 as yellow.

There are a few questions already out there but I've not been able to modify any of the answers to suit this application. I'm thinking I may have to use an if function and couple it with `bgcolor="#008000"` for example but I'm not sure how to incorporate this into the codes snippet below.

```
$select = $_POST['correlation'] ?: '447';

$myQuery = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM ' . 'afl_player_correlations' . ' WHERE Player_ID = '. $select . ' AND COV >= 0 ORDER BY ' . COV . ' DESC');

if($myQuery){
echo '<div style="overflow-x:auto;">';
echo '<table class="splits">';
    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<th>Teammate</th>"; 
    echo "<th>Games</th>"; 
    echo "<th>Co-Variance</th>"; 
    echo "</tr>"; 
foreach ( $myQuery as $result ) 
    {
        echo '<tr><td>'.$result->Teammate.'</td><td>'.$result->Games.'</td><td>'.$result->COV.'</td></tr>';
    }
echo '</table>';
echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$select = $_POST['correlation'] ?: '447';

$myQuery = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM ' . 'afl_player_correlations' . ' WHERE Player_ID = '. $select . ' AND COV >= 0 ORDER BY ' . COV . ' DESC');

if($myQuery){
?>
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
   <table class="splits">
    <tr>
       <th>Teammate</th>
       <th>Games</th>
       <th>Co-Variance</th>
    </tr>"; 
    <?php
    foreach ( $myQuery as $result ) 
    {
       if( $result->Games < 10 ){
          $color = 'red';
       }else if( $result->Games > 40 ){
          $color = 'green';
       }else{
          $color = 'yellow';
       }
    ?>
        <tr>
           <td><?php echo $result->Teammate;?></td>
           <td style="background-color: <?php echo $color;?>"><?php echo $result->Games;?></td>
           <td><?php echo $result->COV;?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this worked perfectly. I really appreciate you taking the time to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ( $myQuery as $result ) 
{
    $style = "background-color: ";
    if ($result->Games < 10) {
        $style .= "red;";
    }
    else if ($result->Games < 40) {
        $style .= "yellow;";
    }
    else{
        $style .= "green;";
    }
    echo '<tr><td>'.$result->Teammate.'</td><td style="$style">'.$result->Games.'</td><td>'.$result->COV.'</td></tr>';
}
```